# jsp/servlet Pages redirection

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i have two page JSP `profile.jsp` and `comprofile.jsp`
I will make a direction towards page `profile.jsp` if my attribut booleen `etat`in my table `etat=1` redirection `profile.jsp`
 else if `etat=0` redirection `comprofile.jsp`

### My code

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
         response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        HttpSession Session = request.getSession();
     //   response.getWriter().print("welcome" + Session.getAttribute("idoperateur"));
        // Object getAttribut(int idoperateur);
        String idoperateur = (String)Session.getAttribute("idoperateur");
           int etat;
    try {
        dbcon= new  javaConnectDB();
        conn=dbcon.setConnection();
        stmt=conn.createStatement();
        query="select * from operateur where idoperateur='"+idoperateur+"' ";
        res=dbcon.getResult(query, conn);
         etat=res.getInt(6);
        while(res.next()){
            etat=res.getInt(6);
            lst.add(res.getString("idoperateur"));
            lst.add(res.getString("nom_o"));
            lst.add(res.getString("prenom_o"));
            //lst.add(res.getString("password"));
        }
         if(etat==0){
        request.setAttribute("data", lst);
        RequestDispatcher rd= request.getRequestDispatcher("profile.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
        lst.clear();

        res.close();
    }
    }
         catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println();
    }
}





but it did not work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your etat variable's scope is restricted to while{} loop alone..... then at your if condition **etat** will not be resolved to a variable

Comment: and I need to do what?? Sir

Comment: declare your etat above the try[} condition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144667/discussion-between-pragadez-and-fatoma).

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of try,catch & finally is bad.finally should be used for closing the connections etc.
Anyway it should not be a problem to display the .jsp.

```
RequestDispatcher rd=response.getRequestDispatcher("full path of jsp");//not just the file name.
```

You should mention the complete path when you are dispatching to RequestDispatcher.

If you can mention the specific error you are getting i can help.

Comment: my question How I can transfer the user to a page according to their state? if `etat=1 ==> profile.jsp` , if `etat=0 ==> comprofile.jsp`

Comment: It should work with whatever the code you have written and declare your variable outside that while loop ,did you try to run the web app? what error you are getting?

Comment: my error is `java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable etat
  location: class com.tut.serve.profile`

Comment: change your etat variable location and shift that if-else condition in finally{} to try{}